# Bluetooth worked in Ubuntu 15.04 but not Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: gnome, software-installation

It very strange. I switched from Ubuntu Unity 15.04 to Ubuntu Gnome 15.04 and now the bluetooth is not working. The button will not stay on.  Does anyone have an idea why? Is there a difference in files installed?

Comment: What make/model is your bluetooth device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution. This has solved the issue for me.

```
sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth
sudo -H gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
```

Change the value of `RememberPowered` from `true` to `false`

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to update this with the anwser, I've been running after all sorts of red herrings trying to figure this out.

Comment: Thanks so much. This issue popped up recently on my Ubuntu Gnome 15.10, not sure why. But this seems to fix the issue for now. If you can't find the **RememberPowered**  just add the line **RememberPowered=false** at the end of the file yourself.